# How to pass objects properties into a generic function

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to create a function that takes in a object property and returns back object property. 
How to get the property values into this specific Function, so that this function only takes takes in the object's specific property and not the entire object?

```
class Program
{

  public T MapFrom<T,V>(T SourceObject.property, V DestinationObject.Property) 
  //Not able to achieve this//
  {
    // Code to Map Property
  }


  // Here I want to specifically pass only one property of Object , not the entire one
  ProgramClassObject.MapFrom<Details,Person>(Details.FirstName,Person.FName)

  }  
}

// Class Containing Property
class Details
{
  public string FirstName { get; set;}           
}

// Class Containing Property
class Person
{
  public string FName { get; set;}           
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it manually, or use some library (see comments, someone mentetioned about it).

If still want to implement yourself:

Prepare some useful `Expression` extensions:

```
public static B GetProperty<T, B>(this Expression<Func<T, B>> propertySelector, T target) where T : class
{
    if (target == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("target");
    }

    if (propertySelector == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("propertySelector");
    }

    var memberExpression = propertySelector.Body as MemberExpression;
    if (memberExpression == null)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("Only member expression is supported.");
    }

    var propertyInfo = memberExpression.Member as PropertyInfo;
    if (propertyInfo == null)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("You can select property only. Currently, selected member is: " +
                                        memberExpression.Member);
    }

    return (B)propertyInfo.GetValue(target);
}

public static void SetProperty<T, B>(this Expression<Func<T, B>> propertySelector, T target, B value)
{
    SetObjectProperty(target, propertySelector, value);
}

public static void SetObjectProperty<T, B>(T target, Expression<Func<T, B>> propertySelector, object value)
{
    if (target == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("target");
    }

    if (propertySelector == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("propertySelector");
    }

    var memberExpression = propertySelector.Body as MemberExpression;
    if (memberExpression == null)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("Cannot recognize property.");
    }

    var propertyInfo = memberExpression.Member as PropertyInfo;
    if (propertyInfo == null)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("You can select property only. Currently, selected member is: " + memberExpression.Member);
    }

    propertyInfo.SetValue(target, value);
}
```

`MapFrom` implementation:

```
public static void MapFrom<TObject, TTarget, TProp>(TObject source, TTarget dest,
    Expression<Func<TObject, TProp>> sourceSelector, Expression<Func<TTarget, TProp>> targetSelector)
          where TObject : class where TTarget : class
{
    var sourceValue = sourceSelector.GetProperty(source);
    targetSelector.SetProperty(dest, sourceValue);
}
```

Usage:

```
programClassObject.MapFrom(details, person, det => det.FirstName, per => per.FName);
```

Comment: sourceSelector.GetProperty(source) is throwing an error

Comment: @ShriRam what type of exception?

Comment: @ShriRam Do you know how to import extension methods? You are missing `usage` for namespace, where have declared extension methods.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're looking for is an [expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx). That's how some libraries like Entity Framework effectively "parse" the code that they're passed.

First, you can get the `PropertyInfo` from an expression through a method such as this. I'm going to explain how to use this below, so bear with me.

```
public static PropertyInfo GetPropertyInfo<TIn, TOut>(Expression<Func<TIn, TOut>> PropertyExpression)
{
    MemberExpression memberExpr;
    switch (PropertyExpression.Body.NodeType)
    {
        case ExpressionType.MemberAccess:
            memberExpr = (MemberExpression)PropertyExpression.Body;
            break;
        case ExpressionType.Convert:
            memberExpr = (MemberExpression)((UnaryExpression)PropertyExpression.Body).Operand;
            break;
        default:
            throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    var property = (PropertyInfo)memberExpr.Member;
    return property;
}
```

Then, the method will become something like this. I've taken the liberty of ensuring the datatypes to be the same here, although you could change `TOut` to `object` if you'd prefer. I did this based on your name of `MapFrom`, which leads me to believe the properties are meant to "communicate" directly.

```
public T MapFrom<T, V, TOut>(Expression<Func<T, TOut>> Source, Expression<Func<V, TOut>> Destination)
{
    var sourceProperty = GetPropertyInfo<T, TOut>(Source);
    var destinationProperty = GetPropertyInfo<V, TOut>(Destination);

    // Use those
    // They're PropertyInfo instances, so it should be pretty easy to handle them however you would have expected to.
}
```

Once you've got all that,

```
var ret = MapFrom<Person, Details, string>(c => c.FName, c => c.FirstName);
```

The signature there could be cleaned up through the use of a generically typed master class, since you wouldn't have to specify any type arguments, and the `string` would be inferred. In a real-world situation, that's likely what you'd want to do, particularly since you appear to be, again, mapping values.

Comment: Console.WriteLine("Please Enter The value for {0}", sourceProperty.Name);
            var value = Console.ReadLine();
            sourceProperty.SetValue(Source, value);
            var retrivedvalue = sourceProperty.GetValue(Source.Type, null);
            destinationProperty.SetValue(Destination, retrivedvalue);

            return destinationProperty.GetValue(Destination).ToString();

Comment: But SourceProperty.Setvalue is throwing target exception error

Comment: It sounds like you need to be passing the objects in with the properties. That's a different matter, but can be accomplished through a similar workflow. You just need to add on two parameters of type `T` and `V` respectively to the `MapFrom` signature, then call `GetValue` and `SetValue` using them. You can't call those against the expressions, because the expressions aren't of the original value's type.

Comment: At that point, though, I start wondering whether there might not be a better way to do what you want to do, or at least a more natural way to set up your classes to do it.