# How to set property value at a later time

Tags: c#, lambda, ref

I am looking for a mechanism which would allow me to defer the setting of the backing field of a parameter only when some condition is met. I had thought the design through until I hit a snag because it required using a `ref` parameter in a lambda expression. Is there a way to do this without needing to put the ref parameter in a lambda?

```cs
protected bool isRunning = false;
List<Action> argumentSetters = new List<Action>();
// the reason for the delegate and following subroutine
// is to define an action which takes a ref parameter
protected delegate void setArgByRef<T>(ref T arg, T value);
protected void setArgByRefSub<T>(ref T arg, T value)
{
    arg = value;
}
protected int _setPoint;
public int SetPoint
{
    get { return _setPoint; }
    set { setValue(ref _setPoint, value); }
}
public void Run()
{
    isRunning = true;
    // time consuming code here
    // don't want SetPoint to be allowed to change
    // while isRunning == true 
    isRunning = false;
    // set SetPoint and other properties after
    argumentSetters.ForEach((a) => a.Invoke());
}
protected void setValue<T>(ref T arg, T value)
{
    setArgByRef<T> a = new setArgByRef<T>(setArgByRefSub<T>);
    if (isRunning)
    // cannot use ref parameter inside a lambda
    { argumentSetters.Add(() => a.Invoke(ref arg, value)); }
    else
    { arg = value; }
}
```

Comment: Can you use a `() => _setPoint = value` action lambda?

Comment: not inside setValue() because that is specific to _setPoint, and the reason I want to use setValue is because this is an abstract class so I want to keep the implementation inside the property setter minimal. SetPoint is just an example, there would be many more props defined in derived classes which should be handled the same way.

Answer (score 3):

The best solution I can think of would involve an `Expression`. The idea there would be to store the property-holding object, the property info, and the value to set, then just set that when you're ready.

Pulling a bit from another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25589964/1270504) I wrote, you could have a function to get a `PropertyInfo` from an expression:

```
public static PropertyInfo GetPropertyInfo<TIn, TOut>(Expression<Func<TIn, TOut>> PropertyExpression)
{
    MemberExpression memberExpr;
    switch (PropertyExpression.Body.NodeType)
    {
        case ExpressionType.MemberAccess:
            memberExpr = (MemberExpression)PropertyExpression.Body;
            break;
        case ExpressionType.Convert:
            memberExpr = (MemberExpression)((UnaryExpression)PropertyExpression.Body).Operand;
            break;
        default:
            throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    var property = (PropertyInfo)memberExpr.Member;
    return property;
}
```

Then you could write a collection of things to set:

```
private static readonly List<Tuple<object, PropertyInfo, object>> _ToSet = new List<Tuple<object, PropertyInfo, object>>();
```

Then add to that list as necessary.

```
public static void AddPendingSet<TType, TProperty>(TType obj, Expression<Func<TType, TProperty>> expr, TProperty val)
{
    var prop = GetPropertyInfo(expr);

    _ToSet.Add(new Tuple<object, PropertyInfo, object>(obj, prop, val);
}
```

You could even pull that out into two methods and directly pass a `PropertyInfo` when desired. That could come in handy, depending on your implementation.

And, when you need to set them all:

```
foreach (var v in _ToSet)
{
    v.Item2.SetValue(v.Item1, v.Item3);
}
```

You could also, of course, pull out the `obj` parameter and just use `this` instead, if that was more appropriate. And I'd be tempted if this became real-world code to not use `Tuple` just since it's a little messy, but I used it here to make this example minimal and complete. Of course it should work either way.

The issue with this is that it won't work on fields like you're using, but you could set up a property and use `this` and that should work. There might also be a way to make expressions work with fields, I've just never needed to so I'm not sure.

Just for good measure, you would call the `AddPendingState` method like this. I've made up `TypeA` as example.

```
AddPendingState<TypeA, int>(instance, c => c.PropertyName, 2);
```

Comment: I had considered using reflection, but expressions hadn't occurred to me. I will try it out.